# Delete password from sequelize model

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i'm learning Sequelize and i see something weird in the course,

```js
const { Strategy } = require('passport-local');
const boom = require('@hapi/boom');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const UserService = require('./../../../services/user.service');
const service = new UserService();

const LocalStrategy = new Strategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await service.findByEmail(email);
      if (!user) {
        done(boom.unauthorized(), false);
      }
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        done(boom.unauthorized(), false);
      }
      delete user.dataValues.password;
      done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error, false);
    }
  }
);

module.exports = LocalStrategy;
```

My question is, when I want to compare passwords I use

> bcrypt.compare(password, **user.password**);

and when I want to delete the password I use

> delete user.**dataValues.password**

where does dataValues ​​come from, by the way I'm using sequelize

Comment: Check out sequelize docs https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model first two lines tells you about dataValues

Comment: it is same to get field from sequelize with `user.get("field_name")`, `user.getDataValue("field_name")` and `user.dataValues.field_name`. Beside field names sequelize holds other metadata about user in User instance like `_previousDataValues`, hooks and so on

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend to delete service props in Sequelize model (`dataValues` prop holds metadata about all fields of a certain model) because it can lead to  incorrect work of this model.
Instead of deleting the `password` field form `dataValues` you need to delete it from a plain object that represents a certain model instance:

```js
const { password, ...plainUser } = user.get({ plain: true })

done(null, plainUser);
```